# Explain the directory structure of a question URL

Tags: support, questions

One of my questions is `https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83998/5275`

Occasionally, I like to delve into some of the technical aspects of the site or try some ideas for programming languages, etc.

What do the last two numbers on the URL represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

83998 is the ID number of that post. Every post (question or answer) has a unique ID number associated with it.

5275 is your user ID number. It's not needed to get to the post, but if you share a link with your user number at the end, then credit is given to your user towards badges like [Announcer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer). When I share the link to that post it looks like `https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83998/759` because my user ID number is 759. If you want you could just use `https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83998` and it would work just fine.